# can anyone please explain me why the two "results" are different?

Tags: c++, reference, return

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    

int & squareRef(int );    

int main() {  
   int number1 = 8;    
   cout <<  "In main() &number1: " << &number1 << endl;     
   int & result = squareRef(number1);   
   // cout <<  "In main() &result: " << &result << endl;    
   cout << result << endl;   
   cout << result << endl;   
   cout << number1 << endl;
}    

int & squareRef(int  rNumber) {   
   cout <<  "In squareRef(): " << &rNumber << endl;      
   rNumber *= rNumber;    
   return rNumber;    
}
```

The program produces the following output:

```
In main() &number1: 0x28ff08    
In squareRef(): 0x28fef0    
64    
1875681984      
8
```

Can anyone please explain why the two "results" are different , is that suppose to be same isn't ?

Comment: What happens if you compile with all warnings enabled?

Comment: why do you think they should be the same? why are you taking addresses of integers and trying to learn something from that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behaviour by returning a reference to a local variable:

```
test.cc:19:7: error: reference to local variable ‘rNumber’ returned [-Werror=return-local-addr]
 int & squareRef(int  rNumber) {
```

rNumber is copied on the stack for the call. After the call, the value on the stack is undefined, and might well change due to subsequent calls. The reference you return only points to that location on the stack and does not hold the actual value.

In general, when these things happen, it is very helpful to turn on all warnings your compiler can give you. With gcc, the flags `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` provide you with a lot of helpful warnings, such as these. In general, code should compile without throwing *any* warnings (except maybe unused variables/parameters in function stubs, although there are macros to explicitly skip over these).

Comment: Being pedantic: not a temporary.

Comment: @JosephMansfield true :) (fixed it)